# Prove that the given function is bijective

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Let $X$ be a non-empty set. Let $\mathscr{F}$ be the set of all functions with domain $X$ and codomain the 2-element set $\{0,1\}$. Define $$h:\mathscr{P}(X)\rightarrow\mathscr{F}$$ by $$h(A)(x)=\begin{cases}
0 & x\notin A\\
1 & x\in A\\
\end{cases}$$ for all $x\in X$ and all $A\in \mathscr{P}(X)$. Prove that $h$ is a bijection.

I can't really get my head around this. I am pretty confused by the definition of the function, and so I don't know how to approach the problem. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please read the tag descriptions before using the tags. You will see that this is not a question about set-theory.

Answer (score 1):

If $\chi_A(x) = \begin{cases} 1, & x \in A \\ 0, & x \notin A \end{cases}$ is the characteristic function for a subset $A \subset X$ then the function $h$ is simply the map $$h: A \mapsto \chi_A.$$

Surjectivity: If $f \in \mathscr{F}$ then let $A = \{x \in X \, : \, f(x) = 1 \}$ and show that $f = \chi_A = h(A)$ (which is to say that for every $x \in X$ it is true that $f(x) = \chi_A(x)$. To this end it will help breaking $x \in X$ down into cases of whether $x \in A$ or $x \notin A$. For instance, if $x \in A$ then by definition of $A$ we have $f(x) = 1$, and by definition of the characteristic function for $A$ we also have $\chi_A(x) = 1$, so that $f(x) = \chi_A(x)$.)

To prove injectivity, suppose $A,B \subset X$ are distinct. Without loss of generality we may assume $A \not\subset B$ so that there is some $x \in A \backslash B$. Then $$h(A)(x) = \chi_A(x) = 1$$ while $$h(B)(x) = \chi_B(x) = 0.$$ Thus $h(A) = \chi_A \neq \chi_B = h(B)$. This proves injectivity

Comment: I think I understand how to show injectivity - you assume the inputs are not the same and show outputs can't be the same. I follow the reasoning for this specific case too and it makes sense. Could you please explain/expand on the proof for surjectivity?

Comment: I expanded a bit

Answer (score 1):

$h$ takes an element $A\in \mathcal{P}(X)$ (which, by definition of the power set, is some subset of $X$, i.e. $A\subset X$) and maps it to a function $h(A):X\to\{0,1\}$ which tells us if elements of $X$ are in $A$.

$h$ is 1-1 means if you take two different elements in the domain of $h$ (say, $A\neq B$ where $A\subset X$ and $B\subset X$), then $h(A)\neq h(B)$. What does it mean for two functions (with the same domain) to not be equal? It means that for some element in the domain, evaluating one of the functions at that element gives you a different value than when you evaluate at the other. Here, it means there exists some $x\in X$ so that $h(A)(x)\neq h(B)(x)$.

$h$ is onto means for each $f\in \mathcal F$, there exists some element $A$ in the domain of $h$ so that $h(A)=f$. An arbitrary element $f$ of $\mathcal F$ is a function mapping $X$ into the set $\{0,1\}$, i.e. $f:X\to\{0,1\}$. So each $x\in X$ satisfies either $f(x)=0$ or $f(x)=1$. Then we can write for $f\in\mathcal F$ given, $V=\{x\in X:f(x)=1\}$ and $V^c=\{x\in X:f(x)=0\}$, and note that $V\cup V^c=X$, and the two sets are disjoint. Can you find the set $A\subset X$ so that $h(A)=f$?

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your head:  $X$ is a set with elements $\{x\}$ (countable, uncountable, finite, we don't know).  And $\mathscr F$ is a set whose elements are functions, $\mathscr F=\{h_{\alpha}: X \rightarrow\{0,1\}\}$.   And $\mathscr P(X)$ is simply the collection of all subsets of $X$.

So we want to map a subset $A \subset X$ into a function by making a function $h_{A}$ where $h_{A}(x) = 1 \iff x \in A$.  Likewise we want to take a function $h$ and create a subset $A_h$ where $x \in A \iff h(x)=1 $.

Perhaps an example:

Let $X - \{a,b,c\}$.  Then $\mathscr P(X) = \{\emptyset, \{a\},\{b\},\{c\},\{a,b\},\{a,c\}, \{b,c\}, \{a,b,c\}\}$. And $\mathscr F = \{h_1:\{a,b,c\}\rightarrow \{0,0,0\}--$

$\{h_2:\{a,b,c\}\rightarrow \{1,0,0\}--$

$\{h_3:\{a,b,c\}\rightarrow \{0,1,0\}--$

$\{h_4:\{a,b,c\}\rightarrow \{0,0,1\}--$

$\{h_5:\{a,b,c\}\rightarrow \{1,1,0\}--$

$\{h_6:\{a,b,c\}\rightarrow \{1,0,1\}--$

$\{h_7:\{a,b,c\}\rightarrow \{0,1,1\}--$

$\{h_8:\{a,b,c\}\rightarrow \{1,1,1\}--$

You need to show that:

$h_1 \rightarrow \emptyset$

$h_2 \rightarrow \{a\}$

$h_3 \rightarrow \{b\}$

$h_4 \rightarrow \{c\}$

$h_5 \rightarrow \{a,b\}$

$h_6 \rightarrow \{a,c\}$

$h_7 \rightarrow \{b,c\}$

$h_8 \rightarrow \{a,b,c\}$

$\}$

is a bijection.